# If a ServerSocket accepts a connection does it continue to wait for further requests?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am using 
ServerSocket(8080,1,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"))

Now in the accept method I obtain the Socket from SS. My question is once I get the Socket and continue with my processing if another request comes in before my processing is complete, will ServerSocket accept that request?

Update: I have a while loop as in the answer below which accepts the connection. My doubt is with this instantiation if I continue with processing of my request and if another connection request comes in will it be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have constructed this ServerSocket with a backlog of **1** there may be only one unprocessed (not `accept()`ed) connection at a time. All additional connection attempts will be refused. In other words, the backlog parameter specifies the size of a queue which stores connections until they are accepted by your program.

Comment: However a backlog of 1 is below all known minima. In practice it will be adjusted *upwards* to the platform's default, which is commonly 50.

Answer (score 3):

It will only accept requests if you call the accept method again, so if you wanted to accept multiple connections, you could have a thread that just spins calling the accept method, like so:

```
while(!stop)
{
    socket.accept();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be in a pending state until you call `accept` again. If you get multiple requests coming in, then up to a certain number will be kept queued until you `accept`. That limit is the queue size of the Server Socket.

Comment: It will be in a 'connected' state actually, if it fitted into the backlog queue. If it didn't, the behaviour is platform-dependent.